# When to use rdf:Type vs rdfs:subClassOf

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, semantic-web, rdfs

I am fairly familiar with ontologies and OWL and use them all the time. But one idea has always eluded me and when I try to find a good answer there are always contradictions. That is, when to use rdf:Type vs rdf:subClassOf.

I mapped out the RDF, RDFS, and OWL ontologies as a graph in an attempt to understand the pattern and have also read several explanations. Let me start by sharing some links to the diagrams I made, as well as the explanations and why it hasnt reconciled for me.

RDF/RDFS Type chart:
[image]

RDF/RDFS Class chart:
[image]

OWL Type chart:
[image]

OWL Class chart:
[image]

Looking through this I see no obvious pattern that might explain the meaning of the two verbs. Though I do notice that while virtually every object has a type few of them have a parent class (explicitly).

Next when I look up the answer I get a lot of tutorials and they largely explain "Type" as indicating an individual. Similar subClassing is usually described as subsets with the classes being sets. So for example `cat rdf:subClassOf animal` makes sense but for type it would have to be something more like `mittens rdf:Type cat`. Thats all well and good but when I look at the ontologies I listed above this doesn't seem to match that idea.

For example FunctionalProperty is clearly not an individual but a set of properties that are functional (can only be applied once per object). So one might expect it not to have a type at all. Yet according to the schema FunctionalProperty is a type of Class, **not** a type of Property, but it is a subclass of Property. Why?

My guess, is that the individual vs set explanation is probably just not a good explanation. It seems it has more to do with what functionality is inhereted maybe? For example a FunctionalProperty has the same domain and range as its parent class Property, but a different domain and range than its parent type, which is just an unrestricted class...  Maybe subclassing inherets restrictions where subtyping does not?

I also notice weird things where sometimes subPropertyOf is used for properties and other times subClassOf is used. For example FunctionalProperty is defined as a subClassOf Property and not a subPropertyOf it, which is what I'd expect.

Any explanation to help me understand when to use one vs the other would be very much appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're right to think in terms of inherited functionality.

Consider your example of `owl:FunctionalProperty`. To say that `owl:FunctionalProperty` is a type of Class and not a type of Property, is to say that `owl:FunctionalProperty` is a Class and is not a Property. If `owl:FunctionalProperty` were a Property, it would make sense to use it as a predicate term in a triple-statement, right? Then, you would be able to say something like:

```
<individualA> owl:FunctionalProperty <individualB>
```

But this triple has no clear semantic meaning.

Since `owl:FunctionalProperty` is a Class, we can say that individual entities are members of that class. For example, we can define the property `:hasMother` as a type of functional property:

```
:hasMother rdf:type owl:FunctionalProperty
```

On the other hand, if `owl:FunctionalProperty` were a Property, this would not make sense. Properties, in RDF, do not have members. Only classes have members.

Similarly, `owl:FunctionalProperty` is a subclass of Property because it is a class of properties (a narrower class), not an individual property.

To summarize:

- `owl:FunctionalProperty` is a subclass of Property, rather than a type of property, because it is a class of properties, not an actual property.
- We can tell the above because `owl:FunctionalProperty` has instances/members, namely particular functional properties. Classes can have these, but Properties cannot. Also, it makes sense to use `owl:FunctionalProperty` as a subject or object in a triple, but not as a predicate. This also indicates that it is a class rather than a property.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Thank you, as I do more research it seems this answer is incomplete (yet still helpful so thank you)... Different types of owl restrict type vs classof... In all forms of OWL except OWL/FULL (such as OWL/DL etc) no object can be both an individual and a class. In other words it may have one or more type connections, one or more subClassOf connections but cant have both. What i still find odd however is it appears FunctionalProperty actually breaks that rule.

Comment: "no object can be both an individual and a class" you can use the same IRI for an individual and a class via punning (but cannot pun properties)